# How to get the exact clientX and clientY JavaScript Position into a child div element on a Wordpress Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a highlight hover map built in JavaScript that shows a div 'info box' when I hover a certain area @ https://isidors.com/test/dupex/contact The problem is that my 'info box' div element does not seem to appear at the exact mouse location, as desired, but it is offset with certain values, which I do not understand where they come from. I had to apply some correction to make it show right.

The div element I have put my map in is a child element of other div. Maybe I have somehow to set the clientX and clientY relative to the div element that has the hover map. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#regiuneest, #regiunecentru, #regiunevest, #regiunenord').hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("g, circle, #info-box").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$('#cod').mousemove(function(e) {
    var paraM = e.clientY/4;

  $('#info-box').css('top',e.clientY + $(document).scrollTop() - 600);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.clientX - ($('#info-box').width()/2) - 100);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
});

</script>
```

When everything(see full code sample without corrections needed to work in WordPress https://codepen.io/SilviuIsidor/pen/EweZwR) is on a single page it works fine. When I put it into a Wordpress page, clientX and clientY for mouse position seem to stop working correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for my problem. I just changed the css position attribute of the map to relative and of the info-box to fixed, and removed the corrections I put.

It works like a charm now. Thanks anyone that looked into this post!